# Obi-Wan and Anakin - Who left whom?

Tags: star-wars

In *A New Hope*, Vader states to Obi-Wan the famous phrase:

> When **I left you**, I was but a learner.... Now I am the master.

But at *Episode III* who actually leaves the other one behind is Obi-Wan.

**So, who left whom after all? Just a continuity issue?**

Comment: Anakin effectively quit as Obi-Wan's Padawan and as a Jedi (to put it mildly). Obi-Wan may have left Mustafar first, but Anakin left Obi-Wan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anakin/Darth Vader is not referring to who physically left who somewhere. He means "When I left you" in more of a relationship sense. As we saw in Episode III (unfortunately),

> Anakin made a conscious decision to turn away from the Jedi Order - including his friend and master Obi-Wan - and align with Palpatine instead.

Despite his official rank being that of Jedi Knight, Anakin was still considered Obi-Wan's student at that time, which is one of the reasons they still went on missions together.

By the time of Episode IV, Vader had trained several students himself (with varying degrees of success) and was considered a master of the Dark Side - officially one of the two Sith.

Comment: Sometimes how we interpret things depends on our point of view.

Comment: TL;DR: , it's a problem with English being imprecise. "Leaving" can be physical, or spiritual.